# WCF Reliable session without transport security will not faulted event on time

Tags: wcf, reliability, faulted

I have encountered a very interesting behavior of reliable session. I am using netTcp binding + duplex channel + reliable session.

When I am trying to listen on channel.faulted , if there is security mode is set to transport , faulted event would fire immediately when client disconnects.

However when I set binding's security mode to None or Message, faulted event no longer fires in the same situation.  They will eventually get faulted half of ReciveTimeout on server side which I understands as reliable session would send a heart beat message at that time.

The question is: Why the wcf binding does not get faulted on time?

The workaround for this case is I can manually "ping" connections.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking why it is so? ... or what you can do about it, if anything?

Comment: Yes, sorry being unclear. I wanted to know why it is so and have posted a workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

NetTcp binding by default uses [Transport security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731316.aspx) with [Windows credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731331.aspx). All bindings except BasicHttp and WebHttp are secured by default.

Comment: Yes that's correct. That is why I had to explicitly set securitymode to None and reliable session no longer raise faulted on time.