# Duplex channel Faulted event does not rise on second connection attempt

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-4, duplex-channel

I have regular net.tcp WCF service client, and regular net.tcp **duplex** (i.e. with a callback) WCF service client. I have implemented some logic to constantly reinstantiate the connection in case a service has faulted.

They are created in the exactly same way:

```
FooServiceClient Create()
{
    var client = new FooServiceClient(ChannelBinding);
    client.Faulted += this.FaultedHandler;
    client.Ping(); // An empty service function to make sure connection is OK
    return client;
}

BarServiceClient Create()
{
    var duplexClient = new BarServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this.barServiceCallback));
    duplexClient.Faulted += this.FaultedHandler;
    duplexClient.Ping(); // An empty service function to make sure connection is OK
    return duplexClient;
}

public class Watcher
{
public Watcher()
{
    this.CommunicationObject = this.Create();
}

ICommunicationObject CommunicationObject { get; private set; }

void FaultedHandler(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    this.CommunicationObject.Abort();
    this.CommunicationObject.Faulted -= this.FaultedHandler;
    this.CommunicationObject = this.Create();
}
}
```

The `FaultedHandler()` aborts the channel and **recreates** it using the code above.

The `FooServiceClient` reconnection logic works just fine, it is being reconnected after many faults. Whereas, almost the same but duplex `BarServiceClient` receives Faulted event only from the first `BarServiceClient` instance, i.e **once**.

Why only the firsts instance of duplex `BarServiceClient` gets faulted event? Are there any workarounds?

---

A similar non answered question: [WCF Reliable session without transport security will not faulted event on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703732/wcf-reliable-session-without-transport-security-will-not-faulted-event-on-time)

Comment: Can you post the `this.FaultedHandler` method/s?

Comment: I have updated the question with FaultedHandler code.

Comment: Could you now post the `this.CommunicationObject` property? It may be easier if you could post whole class.

Comment: Actually the code is spread onto three classes. Two of them are factories (Create methods). And the third one is "watcher" class which recreates connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days on the war against WCF I have found a workaround.

Sometimes WCF fires `Faulted` event, but sometimes it do not. However, the `Closed` event is always fired, especially after the `Abort()` call.

So I call `Abort()` in `FaultedHandler` which effectively fires `Closed` event. Subsequently, the `ClosedHandler` performs the reconnection. In case when `Faulted` is never fired by framework, the `Closed` event is always fired.

```
BarServiceClient Create()
{
    var duplexClient = new BarServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this.barServiceCallback));
    duplexClient.Faulted += this.FaultedHandler;
    duplexClient.Closed += this.ClosedHandler;
    duplexClient.Ping(); // An empty service function to make sure connection is OK
    return duplexClient;
}

public class Watcher
{
public Watcher()
{
    this.CommunicationObject = this.Create();
}

ICommunicationObject CommunicationObject { get; private set; }

void FaultedHandler(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    this.CommunicationObject.Abort();
}

void ClosedHandler(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    this.CommunicationObject.Faulted -= this.FaultedHandler;
    this.CommunicationObject.Closed -= this.ClosedHandler;
    this.CommunicationObject = this.Create();
}
}
```